# AngularJS - pass condition into directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a custom directive - let's call it tableDisplay.  I want to be able to show/hide a column based on an attribute (we'll call it show-edit-column which I have working) BUT I also want to be able to, on each row, determine whether or not the given row is editable.  I'd like to do this by passing in another attribute (allow-edit-row-condition) that tells the conditional statement each row should use to determine whether its editable or not.

Something like the following.

```
<table-display show-edit-column="true" allow-edit-row-condition="row.value === 'OK'">
```

I just don't know how to pass row.value === 'OK' in a way that can then be used on each row.  Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: If the row is created with ng-repeat add the allow-edit-row-condition attribute to each repeated element?

Comment: The problem is the allow-edit-row-condition can change depending on the page the table-display directive is used on, so it needs to be customizable.

Comment: what is `row.value`? Is `row` defined in the parent scope of your directive?

Comment: Nope - that's the problem.  row is defined inside the table-display directive.  So what I'm trying to do is pass a condition into the directive to be evaluated inside the directive.

Comment: What are you trying to say with `row.value === 'OK'`? Are you trying to convey that any row with columnName `value` that equals the string `'OK'` should be editable?

Comment: Yes, exactly - any row within table-display that has a value of OK should be editable.

Comment: No no, be more specific. What does it mean that "row has value of OK"? Row has columns that have values.

Comment: Ok, so within the table-display it has an array of row objects.  Each row object will have the same properties on it.  So in this case they'll all have a value.  When that value === "OK" then the row is editable.  Is that what you're looking for?    EDIT: To clarify again - the object may have a different property on a different page that would tell whether its editable or not.  row.isEditable for example.  It will change depending on the page.

Comment: why not just pass a function directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass a function.

On your parent scope define

```
$scope.isEditAllowedForRow = function (row) {
   return (row.value === 'OK');
};
```

Directive scope parameter declared as one-way binding:

```
...
allowEditRowCondition: '&'
...
```

And use it as

```
<table-display show-edit-column="true"
               allow-edit-row-condition="isEditAllowedForRow(row)">
```

Now, in your directive template you can use the condition as

```
allowEditRowCondition({row: row})
```

e.g.

```
<tr ng-show="allowEditRowCondition({row: row})">
```

In Javascript always think about functions.

Comment: Now the directive requires polluting the scope with functions that operate on its internals - doesn't seem like the best approach to me.

Comment: Sulthan - thank you!  Going to try it out now.  New Dev - the upside is that its being used by myself only for now and at worst by other coworkers.

Answer (score 1):

I understand the question. You are trying to pass a text expression of condition that can be evaluated in the context of your internal `ng-repeat`. I would probably advise against that because now your clients have to understand your internal directive structure, because `row` is meaningless in the parent scope (i.e. to the consumers of your directive).

But if you insist...

You'd need to interpolate this expression in the context of each row. So, parse the expression into a function to be exposed on the internal scope. You can do this in your link function:

```
link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
  // get the condition as string
  var cond = attrs["condition"];

  // parse to create a function
  var matcher = $parse(cond);

  scope.matchRow = function(row){
    // evaluate the function in the context of the row
    return matcher({row: row});
  };
```

Then, in your view you could filter based on this condition:

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in src | filter:matchRow">
  <td ng-repeat="col in row">{{col}}</td>
</tr>
```

Or, perform some conditional rendering (editable vs. not):

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in src">
  <td ng-repeat="col in row">
    <input ng-disabled="!matchRow(row)" ng-model="col" class="form-control">
  </td>
</tr>
```

Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ftd9AKZvOggvp3a6SOny?p=preview) to illustrate